# Naming a class in C# ? Noun recommended by MSDN?

Tags: c#, .net, class

The following class defines a template for printing a order invoice to company 1.

Similarly, there are separate classes that define the template for printing order invoices to respective companies.

I have read questions asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787035/coding-guidelines-best-practices), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238028/c-sharp-coding-guidelines), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/4xhs4564%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) where they emphasis this point:

**`Use a noun or noun phrase to name a class`**

But, for eg.

`PrintTemplateClient1` (which is a verb) for naming a class seems to be fine for me rather than using a noun here.

Any ideas how to name this ?

Do kindly let me know if this question does not belong here so i can move to relevant forum.

Comment: eg. `ClientTemplatePrinter`, or leave it as is

Comment: A "print template" is a noun.

Comment: @user2864740: `Client1TemplatePrinter` , `Client2TemplatePrinter`. So, we will have `Client*n*TemplatePrinter` classes ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. don´t you have these anyway, no matter on its actual word-order? However I also vote for Client1TemplatePrinter

Comment: There isn't a lot of need I have ever found to add a `1` suffix to a class name (model issue?)

Comment: @Sayse: Actually thats an example. A real one would be different `MyClientPrintTemplate` such that

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. If I needed to have a *different* class per client I would put the classes (per client) in a *different* namespace, with a more meaningful name, eg as a fetched example: `Report.UMBC.Generator` (where UMBC is an internally well-known/consistent monikor for the given client, and of course make sure to unify around Interfaces as appropriate). I would also look and possibly refactor such that only the code/model-generators that *needed* to be different were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the word "print" is confusing things here. You probably wouldn't think of it as a problem if it were `PdfTemplateClient1` for example. However, I would try to put the noun at the *end* - I'd use `Client1PrintTemplate`, to go along with `Client2PrintTemplate` etc. The part that classes have in common usually comes at the *end* of the name rather than the *start* (e.g. `TextReader`, `StreamReader`, `StringReader`).

That said, I'd also try to avoid having different *code* for different companies in the first place... this sounds like the kind of thing that should be handled with *data* if at all possible - you might want different template renderers for different output formats, but I'd try to avoid them being different for different companies.

Comment: `TextReader`, `StreamReader` -- Well put examples. Thanks Jon

Comment: +1. To see something really confusing - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo and try to name your classes in a way that does not require linguistic degree :)

Answer (score 3):

You are already using a noun: PrintTemplate. A "print template" is a thing. The fact that the word "print" is also a verb does not change the fact that a "print template", which is a template for printing, is a noun.

Comment: Thanks Igby :) Well said.

Answer (score 1):

```
I recommend changing the way you are defining your classes


    public interface IClientTemplate {

           GetTemplate(int templateTypeID, int clientID);

    }


    public class ClientTemplate: IClientTemplate {

        public string GetTemplate(.. get template as xml.. ) { }
    }


    public interface IPrintService {
              ClientInvoice(int clientID);
              ClientMemo(int clientID);
   }



public class PrintService: IPrintService {

        public ClientInvoice(int clientID) {

                 var template = new ClientTemplate ().GetTemplate(2, clientID);
                 .... and print her... 
            }

   }
```

With this approach you will be able be able to test the project.
In addition, there is a modularity as well.

Answer (score 1):

As a common rule, it's better if a class names reads in English revealing it's purpose.
Name should start with an English sub-phrase representing a class, and end with a sub-phrase representing a abstract category of the class.

In your case, PrintTemplateClient does not read in English as something naming a
'Company-One client printing template'.

It could be CompanyOneClientPrintingTemplate, given there are templates exist for other companies, and they derive from common base class:
class CompanyOneClientPrintingTemplate : ClientPrintingTemplate {}
class CompanyTwoClientPrintingTemplate : ClientPrintingTemplate {}

It's perfectly ok to use whatever grammatical part of speach which reflects the purpose of a class.

For example, if a class represents command, it should start with a verb, and end with word Command, in case of a messaging-based system.
(See [CQRS Documents by Greg Young](http://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf))

For example:

MakeClientReservationCommand - a class that represents a command which would result in action of making a reservation for a client, if carried out by a system.

A corresponding class representing an event that have happened as a result of a command should be a statement in past tense:

ClientReservationCreated
ClientReservationRejected

As you can see, the names of the classes follow the general rule stated - they all read in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what has been recommended is on point, if you are having trouble thinking of a way to name your class try thinking about the class as a service and naming it after that, for instance:

ClientTemplateService,
TemplatePrinterService,

etc...